# jQuery POST huge data to a server running on specific port

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am collecting huge information from the user on a page and trying to POST it to my django server running on a specific port but getting 403 due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). I won't be able to use GET as my input data is huge.

how do I get around this problem? Please advise?

Many Thanks.